# Unable run isomorphic single page app on firebase with ES6

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, isomorphic-javascript

I have an isomorphic react app. It has a server.js file inside app/src/ directory.

Server.js

```
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import expressJwt, { UnauthorizedError as Jwt401Error } from 'express-jwt';
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server';
import PrettyError from 'pretty-error';
import App from './components/App';
import Html from './components/Html';
import { ErrorPageWithoutStyle } from './routes/error/ErrorPage';
import errorPageStyle from './routes/error/ErrorPage.css';
import createFetch from './createFetch';
import router from './router';
import assets from './assets.json'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-unresolved
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import { setRuntimeVariable } from './actions/runtime';
import config from './config';

const app = express();

//
// Tell any CSS tooling (such as Material UI) to use all vendor prefixes if the
// user agent is not known.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
global.navigator = global.navigator || {};
global.navigator.userAgent = global.navigator.userAgent || 'all';

//
// Register Node.js middleware
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//
// Authentication
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.use(
  expressJwt({
    secret: config.auth.jwt.secret,
    credentialsRequired: false,
    getToken: req => req.cookies.id_token,
  }),
);
// Error handler for express-jwt
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  if (err instanceof Jwt401Error) {
    console.error('[express-jwt-error]', req.cookies.id_token);
    // `clearCookie`, otherwise user can't use web-app until cookie expires
    res.clearCookie('id_token');
  }
  next(err);
});

if (__DEV__) {
  app.enable('trust proxy');
}

//
// Register server-side rendering middleware
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const css = new Set();

    // Universal HTTP client
    const fetch = createFetch(nodeFetch, {
      baseUrl: config.api.serverUrl,
      cookie: req.headers.cookie,
    });

    const initialState = {
      user: req.user || null,
    };

    const store = configureStore(initialState, {
      fetch,
      // I should not use `history` on server.. but how I do redirection? follow universal-router
    });

    store.dispatch(
      setRuntimeVariable({
        name: 'initialNow',
        value: Date.now(),
      }),
    );

    // Global (context) variables that can be easily accessed from any React component
    // https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
    const context = {
      // Enables critical path CSS rendering
      // https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader
      insertCss: (...styles) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
        styles.forEach(style => css.add(style._getCss()));
      },
      fetch,
      // You can access redux through react-redux connect
      store,
      storeSubscription: null,
    };

    const route = await router.resolve({
      ...context,
      pathname: req.path,
      query: req.query,
    });

    if (route.redirect) {
      res.redirect(route.status || 302, route.redirect);
      return;
    }

    const data = { ...route };
    data.children = ReactDOM.renderToString(
      <App context={context} store={store}>
        {route.component}
      </App>,
    );
    data.styles = [{ id: 'css', cssText: [...css].join('') }];
    data.scripts = [assets.vendor.js];
    if (route.chunks) {
      data.scripts.push(...route.chunks.map(chunk => assets[chunk].js));
    }
    data.scripts.push(assets.client.js);
    data.app = {
      apiUrl: config.api.clientUrl,
      state: context.store.getState(),
    };

    const html = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(<Html {...data} />);
    res.status(route.status || 200);
    res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

//
// Error handling
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
const pe = new PrettyError();
pe.skipNodeFiles();
pe.skipPackage('express');

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(pe.render(err));
  const html = ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <Html
      title="Internal Server Error"
      description={err.message}
      styles={[{ id: 'css', cssText: errorPageStyle._getCss() }]} // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
    >
      {ReactDOM.renderToString(<ErrorPageWithoutStyle error={err} />)}
    </Html>,
  );
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
});

//
// Launch the server
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (!module.hot) {
  app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.info(`The server is running at http://localhost:${config.port}/`);
  });
}

//
// Hot Module Replacement
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (module.hot) {
  app.hot = module.hot;
  module.hot.accept('./router');
}

export default app;
```

I want to deploy my app using firebase. For that I have setup firebase.json like so -

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where app is a firebase function defined inside app/functions/ i.e. src and functions have same parent directory. 
Functions directory has node_modules, properly configured and its working when tested for other functions.

Problem - 
My index.js file inside app/functions is like so -

```
import app from '../src/server';
import functions from 'firebase-functions';

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Firebase is complaining that it doesnt support ES6. How do I get this function to work with ES6? I cannot simply change functions/index.js file to ES5 and hope things will work as when requires are resolved, they'd expect everything inside to be ES5 as well which is not the case as my entire codebase is in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

Make a directory in functions/ say 'build'.

Build your project

Copy all the contents of your ./dist or ./build (wherever your build files are present) to functions/build

Modify functions/index.js as follows -

```
const app = require('./build/bundle.js').default;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Works like a charm